# Polars List Type to Comma Separated String

Tags: csv, python-polars

I have a df that I'd like to groupby and write to csv format. However, one of the columns has a list type that prevents writing the df to csv.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"Column A": ["Variable 1", "Variable 2", "Variable 2", "Variable 3", "Variable 3", "Variable 4"],
                    "Column B": ["AB", "AB", "CD", "AB", "CD", "CD"]})
```

Which I want to group by as below:

```
df.groupby(by="Column A").agg(pl.col("Column B").unique())
```

Output:

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Column A   ┆ Column B     │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str        ┆ list[str]    │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ Variable 3 ┆ ["AB", "CD"] │
│ Variable 1 ┆ ["AB"]       │
│ Variable 4 ┆ ["CD"]       │
│ Variable 2 ┆ ["CD", "AB"] │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```

When trying to write the above dataframe to csv it comes up with an error: *"ComputeError: CSV format does not support nested data. Consider using a different data format. Got: 'list[str]'"*

If trying to convert the list type to pl.Utf8 it leads to an error

```
(df
    .groupby(by="Column A").agg(pl.col("Column B").unique())
    .with_columns(pl.col("Column B").cast(pl.Utf8))
)
```

Output: *"ComputeError: Cannot cast list type"*

If I try to explode the list in the groupby context:

```
df.groupby(by="Column A").agg(pl.col("Column B").unique().explode())
```

The output is not desired:

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Column A   ┆ Column B            │
│ ---        ┆ ---                 │
│ str        ┆ list[str]           │
╞════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ Variable 1 ┆ ["A", "B"]          │
│ Variable 3 ┆ ["A", "B", ... "D"] │
│ Variable 2 ┆ ["A", "B", ... "B"] │
│ Variable 4 ┆ ["A", "B", ... "D"] │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

What would be the most convenient way for me to groupby and then write to csv?

Desired output written in csv:

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Column A   ┆ Column B     │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ str        ┆ list[str]    │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ Variable 3 ┆ ["AB", "CD"] │
│ Variable 1 ┆ ["AB"]       │
│ Variable 4 ┆ ["CD"]       │
│ Variable 2 ┆ ["CD", "AB"] │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: how would you expect the list to be represented in a csv? something like `['CD', 'AB']` would exclude comma `,` as a separator

Comment: The format how the Column B values are shown is not that important in this case. However, the file will be shared with someone who needs to open with excel, that's why I was thinking the csv format first, but you are right it is not maybe the best choice in this case. What would be the recommended alternative for csv so it can still be opened with excel?

Answer (score 3):

There was a [recent discussion about why this is the case.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6038)

It is possible to use `._s.get_fmt()` to "stringify" the lists:

```
print(
   df
    .groupby(by="Column A").agg(pl.col("Column B").unique())
    .with_columns(
       pl.col("Column B").map(lambda row: 
          [row._s.get_fmt(n, 0) for n in range(row.len())]
       ).flatten())
    .write_csv(),
    end=""
)
```

```
Column A,Column B
Variable 3,"[""AB"", ""CD""]"
Variable 1,"[""AB""]"
Variable 4,"[""CD""]"
Variable 2,"[""AB"", ""CD""]"
```

Another way is using `str()` as [@FObersteiner has suggested.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221856/polars-list-type-to-comma-separated-string/#comment132740382_75223383)

```
print(
   df.groupby("Column A").agg(
      pl.col("Column B")
        .unique()
        .apply(lambda col: str(col.to_list()))
   ).write_csv(), 
   end=""
)
```

```
Column A,Column B
Variable 2,"['CD', 'AB']"
Variable 1,['AB']
Variable 3,"['CD', 'AB']"
Variable 4,['CD']
```

The main probem with "stringifying" lists is - when you read the CSV data back in - you no longer have a `list[]` type.

```
import io

pl.read_csv(io.StringIO(
   'Column A,Column B\nVariable 4,"[""CD""]"\n'
   'Variable 1,"[""AB""]"\nVariable 2,"[""AB"", ""CD""]"\n'
   'Variable 3,"[""CD"", ""AB""]"\n'
))
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Column A   | Column B     │
│ ---        | ---          │
│ str        | str          │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ Variable 4 | ["CD"]       │
│ Variable 1 | ["AB"]       │
│ Variable 2 | ["AB", "CD"] │
│ Variable 3 | ["CD", "AB"] │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```

This is the reason for the recommendation of using an alternative format.

Comment: alternatively maybe `.apply(lambda x: str(x.to_list()))` or `.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x.to_list()))`- but as you write / link, as soon as you need to *read* that csv, you're on the hacky side of things.

Comment: @FObersteiner Good point - I've gotten into the habit of forgetting `.apply()` but I suppose for this type of task it offers simpler code - I've added it to the examples.